# fluentnhibernate: default_schema and Formula

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I've noticed that the default_schema setting only works for generated
SQL.
user-provided SQL (in my case: via Map().Formula()) seems unaffected
by the default_schema setting.

Is there any way around this?
I've tried the naive approach by trying to read the default_schema
from the configuration in the mapping-class and then changing the SQL
in the .Formula() call to include the default_schema, but even
accessing the configuration from the mapping-file seems non-trivial.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Regards,
ldx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this myself.

Since it seems impossible to access any configuration in the ClassMap (and I didn't want to start reading config files manually there) and since you can't have dependencies injected in the ClassMap via some IoC framework (Classmaps need a parameterless constructor),
I had to do it the "old fashioned way" with a singleton class:

The singleton:

public class DefaultSchemaProvider
{
    private static DefaultSchemaProvider _instance = null;
    private string _defaultSchema = null;

```
public static DefaultSchemaProvider Instance
{
    get
    {
        if (_instance == null)
            _instance = new DefaultSchemaProvider();
        return _instance;
    }
}

public void SetDefaultSchema(string defaultSchema)
{
    _defaultSchema = defaultSchema;
}

public string GetDefaultSchema()
{
    return _defaultSchema;
}
```

}

During configuration:

```
var nhibernateCfg = new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration();
nhibernateCfg.Configure(ConfigurationFile);
DefaultSchemaProvider.Instance.SetDefaultSchema(nhibernateCfg.GetProperty("default_schema"));
```

in the classmap:

```
public class CustomerMap : ClassMap<Customer>
{
    public CustomerMap()
    {
        var defaultSchema = DefaultSchemaProvider.Instance.GetDefaultSchema() + ".";

        Table("Customers");

        Id(x => x.Id).Column("Customer_id");
        Map(x => x.Description).Column("Name");
        Component(c => c.CustomerType, c =>
        {
            c.Map(x => x.Id).Column("Customer_type");           
            c.Map(x => x.Description).Formula(
               "(SELECT ct.value FROM " + defaultSchema + "customer_types ct WHERE ct.field='description' AND ct.typeid = Customer_type)");
        });
        HasMany(x => x.ArticleLinks).KeyColumn("VENR").Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore);
    }                
}
```

Comment: in case someone comes here, it is possible to have classmaps with constructorparameters. `var model = new PersistenceModel(); model.Add(new MyClassMap(someparameter)); Fluently...Mappings(m => m.UsePersistenceModel(model)...)`